# Discount Coupon based on ip address in magento

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

Discount Coupon based on ip address in magento

How do I create a coupon code in Magento community edition, where I want the coupon code to apply the discount % only if a particular IP address is being used?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the following file (with "local" folder or creating an extension):

```
app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php
```

The method you need is:

```
protected function _canProcessRule($rule, $address)
{
    ...
```

Before the following line of code:

```
$rule->setIsValidForAddress($address, true);
```

Please add:

```
$ips     = array('192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2');
$ruleIds = array('1', '2', '3');

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

if (in_array($rule->getId(), $ruleIds)) {
    if (!in_array($ip, $ips) ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will let you apply rules with specified IDs to specified IP addresses. You can further modify this code to take IDs of rules from somewhere or to check specific coupon codes.